# How do I fix my PHP/MariaDB installations?

Tags: mysql, centos, php, mariadb, email-server

I ran the clear_iredmail script found here: http://www.iredmail.org/forum/topic333-iredmail-support-faq-how-to-uninstall-iredmail.html
and accidentally deleted some important config files (and more) on my CentOS6 VPS. Fortunately CentOS keeps some file backups like my /etc/php.ini. Yet my php services installed to my website under /var/www/html were complaining certain PHP functions aren't being defined. Furthermore, none of the services I'm using that run MariaDB are functioning either.
I tried reinstalling PHP but that didn't help.

I know this sounds ridiculous but I was hoping to get some thoughts. Should I just redo everything? I don't know how to move my MariaDB installation to a fresh GNU+Linux box.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your system from your last good backup.